# Computer HDD LED lit all the time while Ubuntu is on

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, hardware, webserver

I have a small web server that uses Ubuntu 16.04.1. All the software is up-to-date. It has an Intel Core i5 processor, 8 GB of DDR3 RAM and 2x3TB hard drives one of which is the main drive.

The server is mainly used for two things: [ActiveCollab](https://www.activecollab.com/) (a web based project management system) and [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) (file sync and sharing system).

The server has been working almost non-stop for about a year now. I restart it every 1 or 2 weeks, sometimes more often. And it'd been working like a charm.

Its mysql database is pretty heavy because the ownCloud instance has about 2.4 TB of data and one of the main ownCloud database tables weighs about 2.5 GB.

The main drive, where ownCloud data and everything else is currently stored has about 80 GB of free space.

The problem is that recently the server's HDD LED light is constantly on, all the time and I have no idea why. It feel slower when accessing the web services (ActiveCollab and ownCloud) and sometimes I even have trouble accessing remotely via SSH because it timeouts.

I thought it might be a pending active network connection transferring data but even if I disconnect the server from the network nothing changes.

I recently tried configuring sendmail on the server. I didn't finish configuring it but I don't think it could break the server so badly.

I have been checking the system monitor and both CPU and RAM are in completely acceptable levels (CPU at about 10-30% variable, RAM at about 25% of usage) and the swap doesn't even use 5%.

I have thought this might be because of the lack of free space but my own computer has much less space proportionally and it never does that.

What could be causing the issue?

Is there some tool which can show me like Windows' Task Manager how much HDD in realtime apps use? I tried both Ubuntu's task manager and system monitor but they only show RAM and CPU in real time.

Comment: I suggest `iotop` to look for I/O intensive process.

Comment: That did the trick, it was indeed sendmail logging errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with iotop as @solsTiCe recommended and i saw that the top of the resource usage was by jbd which I later investigated [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/jbd2-sda1-8-what-exactly-is-this-process-that-keeps-running-every-few-seconds-788810/) and it resulted it was a journaling process which was editing logs.

[Screenshot of iotop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKY2O.png)

I went to `var/log` and by using `watch ls -lS` i observed the biggest files there and which ones were changing and it resulted that the ones being edited were related to sendmail and mail errors.

So, the solution was to login as root and `/etc/init.d/sendmail stop` and the LED light immediately went off.

I now have to configure sendmail correctly but in the meantime the problem was solved.